# What's my mistake in send a confirmation email in ASP.net with C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp

This my code that i wrote it

```
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@xxx.com", "My site                Registratration");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email, name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
        msg.Subject = "xxx- Register Account";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.None;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/ActiveMail.htm"));
        string temp = sr.ReadToEnd();
        temp = temp.Replace("[###Name###]", name).Replace("[###Url###]", key);
        msg.Body = temp;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.xxx.com");
        System.Net.NetworkCredential perm = new    System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@xxx.com", "My host email's password");
        smtp.Credentials = perm;
        smtp.Send(msg);
```

it seems that it must work 
but at the smtp.Send(msg) part i receive the error that email failed to send.
Is there any one to help me?
Thanks alot

### Stack Trace:

```
[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 110.4.46.160:25]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +225
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +279

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) +6054548
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +314
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +21
   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +322
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +146
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +170
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +50
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1484

[SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1811
   NewUser.SendEmail(String email, String name, String key) in g:\Programming\Projects\xxx\xxxWebsite(Mysql)\NewUser.aspx.cs:99
   NewUser.SignupBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in g:\Programming\Projects\xxx\xxxWebsite(Mysql)\NewUser.aspx.cs:69
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10



 System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: Please post full error message and stack trace

Comment: Could you show the exception stacktrace you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works well for me, try setting your host and port:

```
        var email = new MailMessage();
        email.From = new MailAddress("johnnytables@xkcd.com");
        email.To.Add("johnnysmom@xkcd.com");
        email.Subject = "DROP TABLE STUDENT";
        email.Body = "Our student records are gone!";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "127.0.0.1";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("johnnytables@xkcd.com", "password");
        smtp.Send(email);
```

Comment: Tq very much dear friends. My problem was related to my stmp port. when i changed it to smtp.Port = 587; it started working correctly.